# C communication between C program and python program using exit code

Tags: python, c

I am trying to exec a python program from another C program where the return value of the py script is

> int array[3]

can I grab the this array from the python exit code ??

**EDIT:**
if the question is not clear can I make the return code of python script an array of integers instead of int ?? and catch it from C process ??

What I want to achieve??
I am working on a robot , a Raspberry PI with 3 sensors.
The RPi is running arch linux, the C program is the navigator that takes input from a python script that get data from sensors, I am wondering how to get the data ??

Comment: Your question is not clear. the return value from a program on common OSs is an integer.

Comment: ok can I make it an array of integers ??

Comment: Nope. you can try to decode somehow, if the numbers are small, but no. you should use some other form of comunication - I'd say standard output.

Comment: Please give some more information about what and why are you trying to achieve. And on which OS. By the way: There is no such thing like "C process" or "Python proces". only "process".

Comment: Ok please check the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

No. The exit code of a process is a single integer, from 0 to 255. It cannot be an array, nor can it be outside that range.

If you want to return data from a C program to its caller, print it on standard output (e.g, `printf()`). The exit status can only convey very basic information, like success/failure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the exit code for this. However, you can use standard input/output:

p.py:

```
print 1, 2, 3
```

temp.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int array[3];
    scanf("%d%d%d", &array[0], &array[1], &array[2]);
}
```

run:

```
$ gcc temp.c
$ python p.py | ./a.out
```